# Erro ao tentar fazer deploy aplicação java tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Boa noite, contratei uma hospedagem no uol host e fui tentar fazer deploy de uma aplicação java. Coloco o .war da minha aplicação dentro da pasta webapps do tomcat, ele tenta subir a aplicação e da o seguinte erro :

```
019-01-03 21:57:51,446 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.19
2019-01-03 21:57:51,447 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Server built:          Jul 24 2017 21:01:14 UTC
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Server number:         8.5.19.0
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- OS Name:               Linux
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- OS Version:            4.9.6-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Architecture:          amd64
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/jre
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b12
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat8
2019-01-03 21:57:51,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat8
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Dnop
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Xms51m
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Xmx204m
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -verbose:gc
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Xloggc://opt/web/logs/1/loggc
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/web/temp/1
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
2019-01-03 21:57:51,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -XX:GCLogFileSize=5M
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=34m
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=17m
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Dcatalina.instance=1
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat8
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat8
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener- Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/web/temp/1
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.12] using APR version [1.4.8].
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2019-01-03 21:57:51,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2019-01-03 21:57:51,750 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol- Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2019-01-03 21:57:51,770 [main] INFO  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool- Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2019-01-03 21:57:51,773 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Initialization processed in 1591 ms
2019-01-03 21:57:51,796 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService- Starting service [Catalina]
2019-01-03 21:57:51,796 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine- Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.19
2019-01-03 21:57:51,882 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application archive [/opt/web/webapps/webservicecpf.war]
2019-01-03 21:57:57,768 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner- At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2019-01-03 21:57:58,176 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/webservicecpf]- 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2019-01-03 21:57:58,454 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/webservicecpf]- Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2019-01-03 21:57:58,454 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader- Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2019-01-03 21:57:58,550 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext- Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jan 03 21:57:58 BRST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-03 21:57:58,849 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext- Registering annotated classes: [class br.com.pedrodev.webservicecpf.config.Root]
2019-01-03 21:58:03,268 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource- Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2019-01-03 21:58:03,858 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean- Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-03 21:58:03,964 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper- HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-01-03 21:58:04,563 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.Version- HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.8.Final}
2019-01-03 21:58:04,566 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment- HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-01-03 21:58:04,757 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version- HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-01-03 21:58:06,129 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect- HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-01-03 21:58:46,084 [Catalina-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report[FutureTask.java:122]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get[FutureTask.java:192]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs[HostConfig.java:778]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps[HostConfig.java:441]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start[HostConfig.java:1588]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent[HostConfig.java:318]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent[LifecycleBase.java:94]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal[LifecycleBase.java:395]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState[LifecycleBase.java:339]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal[ContainerBase.java:956]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal[StandardHost.java:872]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start[LifecycleBase.java:150]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call[ContainerBase.java:1419]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call[ContainerBase.java:1409]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run[FutureTask.java:266]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker[ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run[ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617]
    at java.lang.Thread.run[Thread.java:748]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2019-01-03 21:58:46,108 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol- Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Quando tento acessar o site o servidor retorna o erro 502.
Sabem o que pode ser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

Você está com um problema de falta de memória disponível para a aplicação.

Pelos logs de inicialização acima parece que o Tomcat foi configurado com um limite de memória baixo para o Metaspace.

```
Command line argument: -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=34m
```

O limite do *heapspace* `(-Xmx204m`) também entrega que essa é uma configuração limitada para aplicações bem simples. Não lembro de nenhum ambiente de produção configurado com tão pouca memória em toda a minha carreira (mesmo na minha máquina de desenvolvimento, não é incomum configurar  *containers* que usam alguns GBs de memória).

Eu nunca trabalhei com hospedagem do UOL e não posso te dizer exatamente onde essa configuração foi feita. O padrão, porém, é usar 
variáveis de ambiente.  Geralmente há uma opção na interface administrativa ou um arquivo `setenv.sh` com uma linha parecida com essa:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="[outros parâmetros] -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=34m"
```

Se você tem acesso a essa variável de ambiente pode simplesmente aumentar o tamanho máximo ou remover o limite. Se não tiver acesso eu recomendaria abrir um chamado para o suporte do provedor e investigar a possibilidade de comprar um pacote de hospedagem mais parrudo.

Na ausência da directiva `XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=34m` o *Metaspace* por padrão cresce até ocupar toda  a memória nativa disponível.

É bastante comum também que aplicações possuam *Classloader leaks* . Dessa forma, deploys e redeploys "a quente" em um *container* podem levar a exaustão do Metaspace, mesmo no caso de aplicações relativamente simples. Infelizmente, em boa parte dos casos o código "ofensor" está em alguma biblioteca / framework e não na aplicação principal.

Muitas vezes não há solução trivial para esse problema. Detecção e correção de *Classloader leaks* é um assunto complexo (que não cabe em uma resposta); porém, desde que reiniciar o Tomcat de quando em quando  não seja um impeditivo para ti, o problema é facilmente contornável.